# 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'TextBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my First Appication in MVC2. The following are my View, Controller and another View to display the output.

**StartPage.aspx**

```
<form action="DisplayCustomer" method="post">
    Enter customer id :- <input type="text" name="Id" /> <br />
    Enter customer code :- <input type="text" name="CustomerCode" /><br />
    Enter customer Amount :-<input type="text" name="Amount" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" />
</form>
```

**CustomerController.cs**

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult DisplayCustomer()
    {
        Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
        objCustomer.Id = Convert.ToInt16(Request.Form["Id"].ToString());
        objCustomer.CustomerCode = Request.Form["Id"].ToString();
        objCustomer.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["Amount"].ToString()); ;
        return View("DisplayCustomer", objCustomer);
    }
}
```

**DisplayCustomer.aspx**

```
<div>
    The customer Name is <%= Model.Name %> <br />
    The customer Code is <%= Model.Code %> <br />
    <% if (Model.Amount > 100) {%>
    This is a privileged customer
    <% } else{ %>
    This is a normal customer
    <%} %>
</div>
```

The Above Methodology working fine with me. But I want to change it to the following, which is like that in the tutorial which I am following. I've also included the Error Message here.

---

### The following is want I want to be like

**StartPage.aspx**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayCustomer","Customer",FormMethod.Post))
{ %>
    Enter customer id :- <%= Html.TextBox("Id",Model)%> <br />
    Enter customer code :- <%= Html.TextBox("CustomerCode",Model) %><br />
    Enter customer Amount :- <%= Html.TextBox("Amount",Model) %><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" />
<%} %>
```

Error Message

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named
>   'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting
>   the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the
>   extension method syntax.

**CustomerController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayCustomer(Customer obj)
{
    return View(obj);
}
```

I've provided the link to the tutorial which I am following here. In that tutorial LAB5 is where i've been facing problem, which is at the bottom of the page.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in-7?fid=1631845&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=4684984

I've tried a lot before posting here, no use. Plz help. Remember I am new to MVC and this my very first application.

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: That does not look like a particularly good tutorial (why is it not using [Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax), why use TextBox when TextBoxFor is the obvious choice). Why don't you use the Microsoft offical ones on http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 1):

Currently MVC 5 had been released, You have MVC3 that more complete and MVC4 that has many mobile capabilities! Why don't you migrate to a last version?

Or Please install MVC 3 [www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc) And then correct your view as follows

```
  <% using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayCustomer","Customer",FormMethod.Post))
 { %>
     Enter customer id :- <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Id)%> <br />
     Enter customer code :- <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.CustomerCode) %><br />
     Enter customer Amount :- <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Amount) %><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" />
<%} %>
```

Comment: Hai Bellash. I've tried in your way. But getting the following Error. **An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation**

Comment: @krishna Your `Model` is `dynamic`? Why?

Comment: @Luaan May I tell U one thing Luaan. I am confused that why my model is dynamic. I've been learning ASP.net for the past 6 months and from yesterday onwards trying to learn MVC. I am hopeless. Do U give me a suggestion like a link to a good tutorial or an E-book... something like tat.. Plz :(

Comment: @krishna I'd use the tutorials Liam suggested, at http://www.asp.net/mvc. And if you can, do use the latest MVC version. Also, if you can, use Razor (`*.cshtml`) instead of the old ASP.NET engine (`*.aspx`), it's much more convenient and cuts down on the amount of special characters you need (instead of `<%= ... %>`, you have just `@...`).

Comment: @krishna I was facing same issue, i make my View strongly types (of type Model i can say in your case), and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you might be using the plain view that is not bound with the model. You need to use the Strongly Typed view that binds the view to the model as here "Customer" Model and then write the HTML helper.

Comment: welcome to SO, please post the answer along with a simple code sample or referencing a related SO answer about strongly typed view. For instance, @model Customer